# How to stringify an array of tuples?

Tags: swift

Consider a simple array of tuples of Doubles:

```
let sst = [(1.0,2.0),(3.0,4.0)]
```

How can it be stringified? Here was my attempt:

```
let ssr = sst.map{ f in String(f) }.joined(separator:",")
```

And here's the result:

```
error: repl.swift:32:33: error: type '(Double, Double)' cannot conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
        let ssr = sst.map{ f in String(f) }.joined(separator:",")
                                ^

repl.swift:32:33: note: required by initializer 'init(_:)' where 'T' = '(Double, Double)'
        let ssr = sst.map{ f in String(f) }.joined(separator:",")
```

The desired output is

```
["(1.0,2.0)","(3.0,4.0)"]
```

Comment: Why not simply `let ssr = "\(sst)"` ?

Comment: Add the result that you are expecting.

Comment: @PGDev added the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the hint from @MartinR :

```
 "\(sst)"
$R2: String = "[(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
```

That is not exactly what I needed but it provided the key hint that `String()` is just more limited than expected but we can use the language-level stringification instead:

```
let sst = [(1.0,2.0),(3.0,4.0)] 
let sout = sst.map{("\($0.0)","\($0.1)")}
print(sout)

[("1.0", "2.0"), ("3.0", "4.0")]
```

Now that is still not the final desired output. Some unfortunate drudgery gets us to the end product:

```
let sout = sst.map{"(" + "\($0.0)" + "," + "\($0.1)" + ")"}
sout

[0] = "(1.0,2.0)"
[1] = "(3.0,4.0)"
```

So this is a lot of work to `stringify` the tuple. I hope there were a more concise and clear way.